# Update dictionary key based on value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
players = {'Roger': ['player1', 'dA'], 'Luka': ['player2', 'sK']}.
```

I want to update the key that contains `'player2'`,  but
I can't update players`[Luka]` because `'player2'` is not always `Luka`. How can I select keys linked to `'player2'`?

*(for those wondering, `dA = Ace of Diamonds`, `sK = King of Spades`. These values will also be different every time).*

Edit:
Here's the part of my code: (It won't run because I left out a lot of clutter)

```
qPlayers = 2  #Amount of players
def game(qPlayers):
    players[nr]["value"].append(new_card)
    deal_to =[]
    for player in players:
        deal_to.append(player)
    deal(qPlayers,deck,players,deal_to)

def setup(qPlayers):
    playerhands = []
    for x in range(1,qPlayers+1):
        player = {}
        player["name"] = input("Enter your name, player {}\n>>>".format(x))
        playerhands.append(player)
    return playerhands      


def deal(qPlayers,deck,players,deal_to):
    nr = -1
    for player in deal_to:
        nr +=1
        new_card = getCard(deck)   #getCard produces a random card like sA, k9, cQ
```

Comment: So why not use `'player1'` and `'player2'` as the keys and store the name in the value, instead? You otherwise have to search through all the values to find the one that matches, which is really inefficient, making it pointless to use a dictionary in the first place.

Comment: I was considering to do exactly that. I asked this question not really to solve this particular problem, but rather to ask if it is even possible to do so. And how to do so.

Comment: ... or use a list with two sub-lists, or just use two variables `player1` and `player2` instead of a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. Search through the entire directory, checking for the value which contains 'player2'. This ends up being inefficient, and makes the dictionary structure somewhat useless.
2. Use a list instead of a dictionary, and model your data accordingly, similar to the example below.

An advantage of this data structure is that you don't need the redundant `player1`/`player2` identifiers, since the list index provides that implicitly. To reference `player2` you'd take the second element from the list (`players[1]` since indexing starts at 0).

```
players = [
    {'Name' : 'Roger', 'Value' : 'dA'},
    {'Name' : 'Luka', 'Value' : 'sK'}
]
```

Comment: So a dictionary in a list?

Comment: @RnRoger Yep, or some variation of that based on what you need

Comment: So how would I get or add cards to a player? (I've been trying but can't figure it out)

Comment: @RnRoger if a player can have multiple cards, change the value property to be a list instead of a string `'Value' : ['dA', 'hQ', 'sK', ...]`. Then the list of a player's cards is `players[i]['Value']`, where `i` is the player index. You can add/remove from that list, or get the player's first card using `players[i]['Value'][0]`.

Comment: Can you point out what I'm doing wrong? I added my code in the post itself. (I am trying myself, but I just can't get it to work. I'm pretty new to libraries but do want to use them.)

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can keep track of which `key` in the `dict` contains your `player2` value, or else you will have to iterate through the `dict` until you find a `key` that does. If you frequently need to search based on something internal to the `value`, you may want to reconsider the data structure you are using to store this data.

```
def findKeyWithValue(value):
    for playerName, playerData in players.items():
        if value in playerData:
            # your code here
```

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty useful. It would be a whole lot easier if dictionaries just were in the same order of keys added. I know there are ways to do that but they're too complex for me.

Comment: If you want an ordered `dict`, you shouldn't be using a `dict`. @nbrooks has a good example that will probably work better for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the dictionary to find the key to update. `dict.iteritems()` will do that job in python 2.7.

```
players = {'Roger': ['player1', 'dA'], 'Luka': ['player2', 'sK']}

for key, value in players.iteritems():
    if value[0] == "player2":
        players[key][1] = "sQ"

print players
```